# Show Store name by group in Alphabetical - php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to show stores name in alphabetically format. I have a store table where I am storing all details about a store including its name, logo, discription etc. I want the name will appear as a alphabetical group wise. Such as shown in example. and also show stores by clicking on [A] [B] [C] .... [Z]

```
A
        --> 'Amazon'
        --> 'Apple' 
B
        --> 'Ba...'
        --> 'Be...' 



 <?php 
$temp = array(); // would also generate a dynamic array
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(`name_en-GB`, 1 ) AS FirstLetter, `name_en-GB` FROM `store` ORDER BY FirstLetter, `name_en-GB`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $temp[$row['FirstLetter']][] = $row['name_en-GB'];

    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100bestbuy.com
        )

    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adlabsimagica
            [1] => Airasiago
            [2] => Airtel                
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Babyhugz
            [1] => Babyoye
            [2] => Bagskart
            [3] => Basicslife
            [4] => Bata             
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Clifton
            [1] => Coke2Home
            [2] => Condompoint
            [3] => Croma
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dabur
            [1] => Dealofthedayindia.com
            [2] => Dhamaal
            [3] => Dominos
        )
```

Comment: Why dont you **ORDER BY** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another array to save position where you are.
Something like this:

```
<?php 
    $temp = array(); // would also generate a dynamic array
    $position = array();
    foreach (range('0', '9') as $i) {
        $position [$i] = 0;
    }
    foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i) {
        $position [$i] = 0;
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(`name_en-GB`, 1 ) AS FirstLetter, `name_en-GB` FROM `store` ORDER BY FirstLetter, `name_en-GB`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $pos = $position[$row['FirstLetter']];
            $position ['FirstLetter'] ++;
            $temp[$row['FirstLetter']][$pos] = $row['name_en-GB'];
    }  
?>
```

Now you have an array with positions in subarray.
Should be working, just be carefully to have all firstletters uppercase/downcase or verifiy before

Comment: Thanks for suggestion... But Code not work.. And not showing any result.

Comment: Hi, i edited the code, now should work. Was my mistake, sorry.